# Error when running a C program in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, mingw-w64

It shows: `mingw32/bin/id.exe: can't open output file sample input.exe: permission denied`

When I run a C program in Eclipse it shows this in the console output:

```
C:/Mingw/bin)../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/Id.exe: cannot open output file sample input.exe: permission denied
```

Comment: is `input.exe` still running when you try to build?